# GPS Location finder

Tags: iphone, ios, gps, location

I want to add this condition to GPS that it find locations upto like ten miles. I had already detected user current location but don't know how and where to put this condition.

Comment: Please give some more info of what you want. In which platform? iphone? android? winMobile?

Comment: platform is iphone. Actually i need in my app that it find locations within 10 miles. Like i search for the restaurants, location is within 10 miles where i am present.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose when you search for restaurants you got a list of restaurants with their location. Now you can get your current location using CoreLocation manager. You can filter the list by calculating the distance using CorLocation API

```
CLLocationDistance meters = [restaurantLocation distanceFromLocation:myLocation];
```

Comment: But the condition is not applied yet.